# Changing the location of a plugin gradle file with Ionic2 when adding the android platform

Tags: cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have a project where I'm using `Ionic2` / `Cordova Plugins` / `Android`.

```
> mkdir stackoverflow-question
> cd stackoverflow-question
> git clone https://github.com/napolev/stackoverflow-question.git .
> npm install
> ionic platform add android
> ionic run android -l
```

My problem is that when I add the android platform the following directory is created:

```
/platforms/android/cordova-plugin-hash-generator
```

This directory is created to save inside it the file: `testercordovaplugins-build.gradle`, which takes care to include some third party libraries I use on one plugin I did by myself: `cordova-plugin-hash-generator`.

Everything compiles and runs well. I just wanna do a location change, from:

```
platforms/android/cordova-plugin-hash-generator
```

to (for example):

```
platforms/android/gradle/cordova-plugin-hash-generator
```

so I can do the same for other plugins, preventing all these directories to be created on: `platforms/android/`. Just for organization purposes.

Any idea on how to do that?

This basic application makes use of the plugin I created just to output the md5 summary of the word: `hello` (something basic).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Cordova configuration to change the directory in which your plugin gradle file is placed, so you'd need to move it manually, e.g. using a custom hook script.

For example, if your plugin has:

`myplugin/plugin.xml`:

```
...
<platform name="android">
    <framework src="mygradle.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
</platform>
...
```

Then Cordova will deploy your Gradle file to `platforms/android/myplugin/mygradle.gradle`. This is the default behaviour of Cordova: it places your gradle file inside of a directory named with your plugin ID.

So if you wanted to move your Gradle file somewhere else (e.g. `/platforms/android/gradle/`), you could use a hook script something like this:

`myplugin/plugin.xml`:

```
...
<platform name="android">
    <framework src="mygradle.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
    <hook src="myhook.js" type="after_plugin_install" />
</platform>
...
```

`myplugin/myhook.js`:

```
var myPluginId = "myplugin";

module.exports = function(ctx) {
    var path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path');
    var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs');

    var cwd = ctx.opts.projectRoot;
    var pluginId = ctx.opts.plugin.id;

    if(pluginId !== myPluginId) return;

    var sourcePath = path.resolve(cwd, "platforms", "android", pluginId);
    var targetPath = path.resolve(cwd, "platforms", "android", "gradle", pluginId);

    fs.renameSync(sourcePath, targetPath);
};
```